# wf - passing an approval value to an activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have an Activity( waiting for an approval ) that contains a WhileActivity. In the while activity I want to read the value of an argument - if it returns true I execute I continue with workflow execution, otherwise I stop the hanging the executing till the argument value turns true

How can I do this - for a while or other activities - ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the value you are waiting on is being changed by another activity you can use a TrackingParticipant to watch for the value changing and when that happens resume a bookmark to notify your waiting activity.

Comment: I'm using re-hosted designer, is the TrackingParticipant helps me in this ? I just want when the user drag&drop the activity and run it, it waits the values which they needs. thank you

Comment: What designer you use is not important as this is a run-time issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like your requirements would be better served by a [State Machine](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-b4b808a8) workflow.

---

Okay, so you don't want to use a State Machine workflow.  So, here's how you do it.

You have to create a custom Activity that is used in conjunction with a [Workflow Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/06/08/wf4-workflow-4-0-hosting-extensions.aspx).  An Extension is just an object that can be accessed by your Activities as the workflow executes and allows your Activities to communicate with the classes that are executing the workflow.

Your custom Activity must be able to create a Bookmark and offload the Workflow.  It does this while you wait for the correct value from your Extension.  You don't need to do this in any While Activity loop.  You just do the following

1. Get your Extension
2. Get the current value you are evaluating on
3. If you aren't happy, create a bookmark
4. When the bookmark resumes, go to step 1.
5. If you are happy, continue execution.

Comment: I just want to wait an argument to execute the condition, is it possible without State Machine?

Comment: @Sofy: A State Machine workflow is just a workflow composed of Activities, essentially.  You can emulate a State Machine by writing custom Activities.  But, why would you do this *when these Activities are already written for State Machine workflows?*